# QGIS Profile Tool - Batch export of multiple profiles

Tags: qgis, dxf, profile

I have a DEM and a vector shapefile of multiple lines and I need to obtain multiple DXF export of each profile based on the position of the lines.
There is a way to obtain multiple exports (many DXF) of it in an automatic way?
With the tool now I can export single profine (as 2D DXF) selecting each line on the vector layer.

Comment: This might help - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331903/cutting-exporting-multiple-terrain-profiles-to-csv-files-with-qgis